# Assistance with lF statement and single loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am tiring to get for every `Empty cell`  `FakeEmail(i).com` i.e so that if there are 3 `Empty cells I get

`FakeEmail1.com`
`FakeEmail2.com`
`FakeEmail3.com`

In there respective cells

I know this is not correct but cant figure out the proper syntactic's
`Cells(i, 4).Value = FakeEmail(i).com`

Thanks

```
Sub AAA()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long
lRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lRow
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, 4).Value = FakeEmail(i).com
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit brettdj, helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
   Cells(i, 4).Value = "FakeEmail" & i & ".com
```